# Dynamically Storing and retriving 3,000,000+words in c#.NET using Collections

Tags: c#, data-structures, collections

How to Store and retrieve 3,000,000+ words in Dynamically without using SQL..

Get a word from a document then check whether the word is available or not.

if available,
     then increment it in corresponding document count...

if not available 
     i.e, New word then create a new column then increment the document count and put Zero 
    to all other documents.

For Example..

I having 93,000 documents each contains more or less 5000 words. If new word comes then add a new column. Likewise 960000 words came.

**----------------Word1 word2   word3   word4   word5   ….----   New Word   …**  **word96000**

**Document1**      ----2    ----19  ----45  ----16  ----7 ----  ------….0   ----..  ----..

**Document2**   ----4   ----6   ----3   ----56  ----3   ----….  --------0   ----..  ----..

**Document3**   ----56  ----34  ----1   ----67  ----4   ----….  --------0   ----..  ----..

**Document4**   ----7   ----45  ----9   ----45  ----6   ----….  --------0   ----..  ----..

**Document5**   ----56  ----43  ----234 ----87  ----46  ----….  --------0       ----..

**Document6**   ----56  ----6   ----2   ----5   ----23  ----….  --------0   ----..  ----..

.                       ….  .   ..  ..

.                       ….  .   ..  ..

.                       ….  .   ..  ..

.                       ….  .   ..  ..

.                       ….  .   ..  ..

.                       ….  .   ..  ..

.                       ….  .   ..  ..

**Document1000**    ----5   ----9   ----9   ----89  ----34  ----….  --------1   ..  ..

Count of those words that are added are dynamically updated in the corresponding document's entry.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Do you want the result to fit into memory so that you can query it, or do you just want the results output to a file somewhere?  There are many ways to approach this, but the best way depends a lot on what you want the final result to be.

Answer (score 2):

Such a sparse matrix is often best implemented as a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int> index;
```

But the question lacks too many details to give more advice.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid wasting memory, I would suggest the following:

```
class Document {
   List<int> words;
}
List<Document> documents;
```

If you have 1000 documents then create `List<Document> documents = new List<Document>(1000);`
Now if document1 has the words: word2, word19 and word45, add the index of these words to your document

```
documents[0].words.add(2);
documents[0].words.add(19);
documents[0].words.add(45);
```

You can modify the code to store the words themselves.
To see how many times the word word2 is repeated, you can go throw the entire list of documents and see if the document contains the word index or not.

```
foreach (Document d in documents) {
   if (d.words.Contain(2)) {
      count++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nWords = (from Match m in Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText("big.txt").ToLower(), "[a-z]+")
              group m.Value by m.Value)
             .ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr => gr.Count());
```

Provide you with a dictionary list indexed by word and count.  I'm sure you could then save the info as each file is read in and then build up your final lists.
maybe?